# What does it mean to get the Value of an Object in C#?

Tags: c#

From, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

What is the construct here,

```
subOptionsAccessor.Value;
```

What does `Value` mean here?  What is getting passed in?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MySubOptions _subOptionsAccessor;

    public HomeController(IOptions<MySubOptions> subOptionsAccessor)
    {
        _subOptionsAccessor = subOptionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var subOption1 = _subOptionsAccessor.SubOption1;
        var subOption2 = _subOptionsAccessor.SubOption2;
        return Content($"subOption1 = {subOption1}, subOption2 = {subOption2}");
    }
}
```

Edit:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1#Microsoft_Extensions_Options_IOptions_1

Am I correct the IOptions type simply means, in this case, the constructor is going to receive a type of IOptions and the Value in this context means one of the list items it contains.  Here that is "MyClass."  And Value means the object in the list sent in the constructor (of type IOptions).

Comment: Presumably `Value` is a field or property of the class `MySubOptions`.

Comment: It's just a property of the [IOptions<TOptions>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1) interface. Classes that implement this interface are required to have that property.

Comment: @adv12 It's a property on the interface `IOptions<T>`.

Comment: @Servy, ah I see that now.

Comment: not as easy to google as one would expect. found one [reference](http://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/): "The IOptions<> service exposes a Value property which contains your configured MySettings class." So obviously it just returns the instance of `MySubOptions` it has constructed.

Comment: That's a lot of downvotes for a specific question.

Comment: Some questions, while asked innocently and sincerely, causes experienced developers to face palm.  Such questions tend to be downvoted.  I suspect that's the case here.

Comment: @dlatikay Well it's not *that* hard to Google... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1

Comment: I did Google.  I didn't understand, so I asked.

Comment: I occasionally see users who ask lots of simple questions with a high rep get penalized for not getting better, it's a shame as I can see you work with a lot of languages.

Answer (score 3):

> What does Value mean here?

It is a property of the `IOptions<TOptions>` interface, which, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1), returns "the configured `TOptions` instance".

> What is getting passed in?

Nothing.  It is *returning* a value - there is no input to a field or property getter.

You seem to think that `Value` is some "special" keyword or property in C#, which is not the case. It's just a normal property on the type - what it returns is whatever it's programmed to return.

As an example, the [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) type is used to wrap a value type (e.g. `int`, `double`) in a reference type that could be null.  *That* type has a [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx) property that returns the underlying value.  But it's *programmed* to do that - there's nothing magic about it that applies to other types.

Comment: What if I have three properties in the object?  What does Value mean there?

Comment: It means the same thing... those other properties will have their own names.

Comment: `Value` is _one_ property.  You seem to think that it's a "magic" keyword that gives you all properties, which is incorrect.

Comment: @D Stanley [this](http://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2) suggests otherwise. `Value` seems to be a property of type T of `IOptions<T>`

Comment: @dlatikay How is that contrary to the statement that it's a property on the interface?

Comment: @servy not at all. but it is not a property of `MySubOptions`, it is *exposing an instance* of `MySubOptions`

Comment: `value` has no special meaning. It could equally have been `FrogSize` or `ElephantTrousers`, its whatever the interface designer wants

Comment: Value is the property of the Interface.

Comment: `Value` is a property on that interface.